# Various Sprites Collide using group Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection

I am creating various class with objects moving randomly in the screen. What I am doing:

```
object = obj(screen)
object2 = Object2(screen)
object3 = Object(screen)
```

then I add the object and the object 2 in a group like:

```
group2 = pygame.sprite.Group(object, object2)
```

and the object3 in a different group like:

```
group = pygame.sprite.Group(object3)
```

Then I am checking the group2 with the group if there is collide, but with this method I don't know which object collide the other object:

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(group, group2, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask):
```

Answer (score 4):

To handle the collision of sprites in two different groups, you can use [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide):

> **pygame.sprite.groupcollide()**
>   *Find all sprites that collide between two groups.*
>
> `groupcollide(group1, group2, dokill1, dokill2, collided = None) -> Sprite_dict`
>
> This will find collisions between all the Sprites in two groups. Collision is determined by comparing the Sprite.rect attribute of each Sprite or by using the collided function if it is not None.
>
> Every Sprite inside group1 is added to the return dictionary. The value for each item is the list of Sprites in group2 that intersect.
>
> If either dokill argument is True, the colliding Sprites will be removed from their respective Group.
>
> The collided argument is a callback function used to calculate if two sprites are colliding. It should take two sprites as values and return a bool value indicating if they are colliding. If collided is not passed, then all sprites must have a “rect” value, which is a rectangle of the sprite area, which will be used to calculate the collision.

---

So, given `group` and `group2`, you can use it like:

```
result = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(group, group, False, False)
```

and the result is a `dict` containing the infotmation you're looking for, as the documentation states.

Comment: Nice one. The result is like:
`{<object1 sprite(in 1 groups)>: [<object2 sprite(in 1 groups)>]}`
So is a dictionary, how can I just access the name of the object, sprite?

Comment: What do you mean by *name of the object*?

Comment: on the above example I want just from the result the words "object1" and "object2".

Comment: Well, it would be an ugly hack to retrieve those names. Why do you want to do this? You already have a reference to sprites in the dictionary. Nonetheless, you could do something like `for a, b in result: if b == object1: ...` but I would not recomment this. What is supposed to happen when a collision occurs?

Comment: I need the name of the object so that to call the class to get some information about the sprite for example
sprite1 = object1.an_atrribute()
So I need the name of the sprite so that to access to the atrribute.

Comment: Why do you need the "name" (you acutally mean local variable) of the sprite? The `dict` returned by `groupcollide` already contains a reference to the sprite, so simply use that.

Comment: Maybe I cant understand what you mean. But the dictionary returned by the command you provide, includes some information which are not neccessary like chars < [ etc. I just want to access the name of the sprites which are collide, for instance: result.keys() to return "object1" and the result.values() to return "object2" so that then i can simple use the result of the values() and keys() to access to the object.

Comment: Is it possible to check for group collisions using masks? The only way I can think of is passing to `collide` a function that calls `a.collide_mask(b)`

Comment: @Alex yes. Just pass the `collide_mask` function as last paramter to `groupcollide`. For example: `(pygame.sprite.groupcollide(group, group, False, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)`.